Comparing Tree Traversal Algorithms: In-Order, Pre-Order, Post-Order, and Level-Order – Applications and Efficiency in BSTs, AVL Trees, and B-Trees
"What are the differences between various tree traversal algorithms (in-order, pre-order, post-order, level-order), and in what scenarios would each be most beneficial? How do these traversal methods impact the efficiency of operations such as searching, inserting, or deleting nodes in different types of trees like binary search trees, AVL trees, and B-trees?"
This question not only covers multiple tree traversal algorithms but also delves into their practical applications and impact on the efficiency of different tree operations. It encourages a discussion on when and why to use specific traversals in various tree data structure

I have personally seen that the post order traversal is used for example to clear memory as it's treating the subtrees before the root node.
Also, in order traversal is used to get the elements of a binary search tree sorted in ascending order.
